# Transform polynomial graph - Multiply by a list of values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib. I have a list of 600 values. I also have an polynomial function that I'm graphing with values between 0 and 600. I'm trying to multiply every point by the corresponding value in the list.

I could evaluate the polynomial in a loop, and do the multiplication there, but I would end up with a graph of points instead of a line.

I think I might need to use the Transformations framework, but not sure how to apply it to the graph.

**Edit:**

```
a = [5, 2, 3 ... 0, 2, 8] # 600 values
poly_a = polyfit(a)

deriv_a = polyder(poly_a)

b = [232, 342 ... 346, 183] # 600 values
```

I need to multiply deriv_a by b.

Comment: How are you plotting the polynomial? is the polynomial a fit of the list of 600 values?

Comment: It's a fit, but of a different list of 600 values.

Comment: then why not just multiply the points that you are fitting? I assume you are using numpy right?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. Updated with code. Thanks.

Comment: lol, now it is even less clear to me what you are trying to do. deriv_a*b is a set of points, why is that a problem? what did you want it to be?

Comment: It sounds like you want `numpy.polyval`? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding things a bit. This is what `numpy` is for (if you're using `matplotlib` it's already converting things to a numpy array when you plot, regardless.)

Just convert your "list of 600 values" to a numpy array and then evaluate the polynomial.

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Your "list of 600 values"...
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 600)

# Evaluate a polynomial at each location in `x`
y = -1.3 * x**3 + 10 * x**2 - 3 * x + 10

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Based on your edit, it sounds like you're asking how to use `numpy.polyder`?

Basically, you just want to use `numpy.polyval` to evaluate the polynomial returned by `polyder` at your point locations.

To build on the example above:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Your "list of 600 values"...
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 600)

coeffs = [-1.3, 10, 3, 10]

# Evaluate a polynomial at each location in `x`
y = np.polyval(coeffs, x)

# Calculate the derivative
der_coeffs = np.polyder(coeffs)

# Evaluate the derivative on the same points...
y_prime = np.polyval(der_coeffs, x)

# Plot the two...
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('Original Function')

ax2.plot(x, y_prime)
ax2.set_title('Deriviative')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I understand how that works, I wasn't very clear in the question. Updated with some code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, the edits make things much clearer. I've updated my answer. I think you're just wanting `numpy.polyval`? Hope that helps!